# update data in one table with the values from another table

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have 2 tables, `shows` and `show_photo`

`shows` structure:

[image]

`show_photo` structure:

[image]

What i want to do is update `show_photo.modified` column with `show.year`
This is what i tried but nothing gets updated.

```
UPDATE show_photo t2
JOIN shows t1 ON t1.id = t2.show_id
SET t2.modified = t1.year;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer:

> Change the column type from `TIMESTAMP` to `VARCHAR` first, run the
>   `UPDATE` query; and again change the data type from `VARCHAR` to `INT`

Your current table has `modified` column set to `TIMESTAMP`. But, you're trying to update its values to integers, which will fail.

Comment: But i want it to be timestamp, how can i later change it back to timestamp without loosing data?

Comment: I ended up converting column to 'datetime' executing slightly modified query `UPDATE show_photo t2
JOIN shows t1 ON t1.id = t2.show_id
SET t2.modified = CONCAT(t1.year, "-01-01 00:00:00");` and then converting back to timestamp (i need timestamp because of on update current_timestamp)

Comment: @pedja It can not be time stamp. You're only storing year in it. It could be `INT` or `YEAR` or `VARCHAR` (and their derivative)

Comment: Because i added `modified` column later, by default its "0000-00-00 00:00:00". What i wanted is just to do this one time, to set modified to the year. This wont be executed from my application, just needed default values

Comment: @pedja See, you missed putting that info in your question :|

Comment: Sorry :(, i will accept your answer because it is a valid answer, for future readers